# Large og:imgae but Facebook shows small square instead

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, social-media, share-open-graph

We are using large image 1920x1080 but after sharing the URL on Facebook, it still shows the small square instead of large image.

We defined og:image

```
 <meta name="og:image" content="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/marketingminer-multimedia/link building průzkum mezi specialisty_1920x1080.png">
```

And tried the Facebook debugger (but not helped): https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.marketingminer.com%2Fsk%2Fblog%2Flink-building-pruzkum-mezi-specialisty.html

URL: https://www.marketingminer.com/sk/blog/link-building-pruzkum-mezi-specialisty.html

What should be the problem?

Comment: One thing to check is your image file’s Content-Type on S3. When I enter the URL for your image into my browser, the browser asks if it should download the image (rather than just displaying the image). In looking at the header file for the image, it’s listing the Content-Type as application/octet-stream rather than the normal image/png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Content-Type on S3 to image/png helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the image on the same domain.